# according to Swagger Open API 3.0 is it possible to reuse components parameters as requestBody properties?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Reading the Open API 3.0 specs, I see that `parameters` can be defined in the `components` section and thus [reused for multiple paths](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#common-for-various-paths) with their relative `GET` operations.

Is there any way of reusing `components/parameters` for a ***different operation*** on the ***same path***? In my API I allow `GET` and `POST` to be used interchangeably (no data ever needs to be written, it's only read), with the same parameters. However in the **Open API** json representation, a `GET` operation can take query **`parameters`** whereas a `POST` operation would take **`properties`** in the `requestBody`. Are `parameters` and `properties` not interchangeable in the Open API 3.0 spec?

Comment: parameters only reusable in `path`, `query`, `header` and `cookie` https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/#structure